# Button keeps doubling in datagridview c#

Tags: c#

```
                    conn = new MySqlConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = connString;
            conn.Open();
            string queryss = "Select * from products where deleted='No'  and secretid='"+ listView1.SelectedItems[0].Tag.ToString() + "'";
            MySqlCommand cmdaa = new MySqlCommand(queryss, conn);
            MySqlDataReader dataReaderxx = cmdaa.ExecuteReader();
            dataReaderxx.Read();
            if (dataReaderxx.HasRows)
            {

                string barcode = dataReaderxx["barcode"] + "";
                string productname = dataReaderxx["productname"] + "";
                string productprice = dataReaderxx["productprice"] + "";

                conn.Close();



                conn = new MySqlConnection();
                conn.ConnectionString = connString;
                conn.Open();
                string queryssqw = "Select * from postempsaleproducts where deleted='No' and referenceno='" + textBox1.Text + "' and productsecretid='"+ listView1.SelectedItems[0].Tag.ToString()  + "'";
                MySqlCommand cmdaass = new MySqlCommand(queryssqw, conn);
                MySqlDataReader dataReaderxxcc = cmdaass.ExecuteReader();
                dataReaderxxcc.Read();
                if (dataReaderxxcc.HasRows)
                {
                    string quantity = dataReaderxxcc["quantity"] + "";
                    int newquantity = Convert.ToInt16(quantity) + 1;
                    conn.Close();

                    conn = new MySqlConnection();
                    conn.ConnectionString = connString;
                    conn.Open();
                    string querys = "Update postempsaleproducts set quantity='" + newquantity + "', dateupdated='" + date + "', timeupdated='" + time + "', updatedby='" + Fullname + "', updatedbyid='" + UserInformation.UserInformation.CurrentLoggedInUser + "' where productsecretid='" + listView1.SelectedItems[0].Tag.ToString() + "'";
                    MySqlCommand cmdx = new MySqlCommand(querys, conn);
                    MySqlDataReader dataReaderx = cmdx.ExecuteReader();
                    conn.Close();


                }
                else
                {





                    conn = new MySqlConnection();
                    conn.ConnectionString = connString;
                    conn.Open();
                    string querys = "insert into postempsaleproducts values(NULL,'" + SecretID + "','" + textBox1.Text + "','" + listView1.SelectedItems[0].Tag.ToString() + "','" + barcode + "','" + productname + "','" + productprice + "','1','No','No','" + date + "','" + time + "','" + Fullname + "','" + UserInformation.UserInformation.CurrentLoggedInUser + "','" + day + "','" + month + "','" + year + "','Computer Software','','','','')";
                    MySqlCommand cmdx = new MySqlCommand(querys, conn);
                    MySqlDataReader dataReaderx = cmdx.ExecuteReader();
                    conn.Close();






                }



                conn = new MySqlConnection();
                conn.ConnectionString = connString;
                conn.Open();
                string selectQuery = "Select  secretid,productname,productprice,quantity from  postempsaleproducts where deleted='No' and referenceno='" + textBox1.Text + "'  order by id desc";
                MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(selectQuery, connString);
                MySqlCommandBuilder bulider = new MySqlCommandBuilder(adapter);
                DataTable table = new DataTable();
                adapter.Fill(table);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
                conn.Close();
                dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "SecretID";
                dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Product Name";
                dataGridView1.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Price";
                dataGridView1.Columns[3].HeaderText = "Quantity";
                dataGridView1.Columns[0].Visible = false;

                DataGridViewButtonColumn btn = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();

                btn.HeaderText = "ʌ";
                btn.Name = "ʌ";
                btn.Text = "ʌ";
                btn.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
                dataGridView1.Columns.Add(btn);

                DataGridViewButtonColumn btn2 = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
                btn2.HeaderText = "v";
                btn2.Name = "v";
                btn2.Text = "v";
                btn2.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
                dataGridView1.Columns.Add(btn2);



                dataGridView1.Columns[2].Width = 50;
                dataGridView1.Columns[3].Width = 50;
                dataGridView1.Columns[4].Width = 15;
                dataGridView1.Columns[5].Width = 25;











            }
            else
            {

            }
```

when i click on an item on the listview it input the data for the item into a database and then it displays in the datagridview. the problem i have is  have added two buttons to the datagridview and when i click the item in list view the button keeps doubling  and making the datagridview look messy,
can anyone help?
This is how i want it and how it shows with the first click
[image]
this is how it appears after second clicks
[image]

Comment: hrm maybe set a width on the buttons

Comment: i have. not only does it become big, the button doubles in number.  you see the first picture the buttons were two, for the second picture it is three and it keeps doubling in number when i click and item.

Comment: Your code is neither setting the size of the button or the column, in fact most of the code is not needed for this question

Comment: `Read` *then* `HasRows`? That's backwards. And `HasRows` is unnecessary if `Read` returns true there. Just do `if (dataReaderxx.Read())` .